# processFormSubmission not being called

Tags: spring

I am new to spring. I am creating a simple login page. But the processFormSubmission() is not being called. But the showForm() is working.

```
public class LoginController extends SimpleFormController

{
    private LoginService loginService;

private String loginView;

public LoginService getLoginService() {
    return loginService;
}

public void setLoginService(LoginService loginService) {
    this.loginService = loginService;
}

public String getLoginView() {
    return loginView;
}

public void setLoginView(String loginView) {
    this.loginView = loginView;
}

public LoginController() {
    setBindOnNewForm(true);
}
@Override
protected ModelAndView processFormSubmission(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception 
{
    TraceUser tr = (TraceUser) command;
    System.out.println(tr);
    //loginService.
    return super.processFormSubmission(request, response, command, errors);
}
@Override
protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("traceUser", new TraceUser());
    mav.setViewName(getLoginView());
    return mav;
}
```

}

And please help me out with how should the ModelAndView object should be processed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the use of the `Controller` API has been left aside in favor of the new annotation-based controllers (see the `@RequestMapping` annotation) and classes like `SimpleFormController` have been deprecated since quite a while now.

However, to answer your question, I assume your form does not declare `method="post"` and by default, the SFC will consider only POST requests as form submissions (see the `isFormSubmission()` method in `AbstractFormController`). Is this the case ?

Comment: form is using POST method only.